# Change something after creating usb with rufus

Tags: rufus

Already created windows 11 USB using Rufus and selected 'create local account with same username'. Can I toggle it off without downloading the iso again?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: While we can make guesses about the details of your situation, we really need you to give us more information in order for us to begin answering your question.

Answer (score 3):

In Rufus, go to `Select`, navigate to the folder where you downloaded the ISO and open it. No need to re-download.

[image]

Comment: Deleted a while ago

Comment: Then you will need to download it again.